# Why is there a non semi positive definite leading minor when applying functional pca on curves where the period=2 in the fourier basis?

Tags: r, pca

I am using the fda package for R to generate a random sample of curves. More specifically, I am using a fourier series with a change in the period to represent the specific structure I need. Defining the sample works fine, but I encounter a problem when the number of basis functions is sufficiently large and I want to apply 'pca.fd' on the sample. The error is:

```
"leading minor of order [... e.g. 24] is not semi positive definite."
```

I am wondering why this happens, and if there is a way to circumvent it. Obviously, it's rather a numerical or statistical issue then a pure coding problem. But all my assigned coeficients are iid and the fourier basis provides orthogonal functions. Moreover, everything works totally fine when the period is set to its default level. So what goes wrong with period=2 ?

I am happy for any hint on the issue. Thank you very much in advance !

Here is some code to reproduce the error:

```
nc <- 40 # Number of curves  
nb <- 101 # Number of basis functions  
coefm <- matrix(rnorm(nb*nc),nrow=nb,ncol=nc) # random coeficient matrix

# basis function object with "normal" period:  
mybase = create.fourier.basis(rangeval=c(0,1), nbasis=nb, period=1) 

# generate the sample of curves:  
fdobj <- fd(coefm,mybase) 

# Principal component analysis:  
pca.fd(fdobj) # should work, even though the number of basis functions is large.

# Now: change the period of the fourier basis object:  
mybase = create.fourier.basis(rangeval=c(0,1), nbasis=nb, period=2)  
fdobj <- fd(coefm,mybase)  

pca.fd(fdobj) # Here is the error. However, this does not happen with nb<20
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this purely on the length of the title

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no easy and straight away answer. I contacted the maintainers of the fda package and after they investigated the issue let me know that what I was doing was simply very bad in terms of what happens to the curves I generated. Apparently, the curves are so similar on some parts of their range, that the pca runs into some kind of numeric difficulties. So to close this issue, I don't expect a better answer anymore.